# How do I get the IP ranges for EC2 instances in specific regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, ip

I need to know what IP subnet will be used by AWS EC2 instances

Reading:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html
- https://superuser.com/questions/989123/amazon-ec2-public-ip-address/989400

I understand that I can use this URL giving the IP ranges:

- https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

But I am a bit confused by the output.

I understand I need to filter on:

- region
- type: EC2

Is my understanding correct ?
If so I get 137 IP subnets which is very important number.

How can I have more control on IP subnets ?

Comment: I see all 3 of the regions you say are missing in the json. I just found them via Ctrl+f in the browser.

Comment: Give each of your individual EC2 instances an Elastic IP, or route their traffic through  a NAT device/gateway with an Elastic IP. Then you can configure the remote firewall with those Elastic IPs, rather than allow the entirety of EC2 public IP space.

Answer (score 2):

It will be **extremely fragile** to base your firewall system on the possible IPs that **any EC2 instance** in those regions can have.

Allowing access from 1 region may arguably have been fine but you're opening up your firewall to **five traffic-heavy & very popular AWS regions**.

That blanket policy allowing all traffic will essentially defeat the purpose of having a firewall that should only allow *specific* traffic through.

If you're actually looking for security, assign your EC2 instances an [Elastic IP (EIP)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) and allow traffic only from those particular IPs.

Depending on how many EC2 instances you have, it may also be much easier, quicker & cheaper (however [small](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/#Elastic_IP_Addresses)) to route all your EC2 instances through 1 [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) with 1 EIP (if you don't need all your EC2 instances to have different public IPs).

You'll save yourself the headache of keeping up to date with possible IP range changes made by Amazon, have cleaner firewall policies and have tighter security by only letting traffic that you're sure is coming from your instances through.

Win, win, win.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my question as the main item is about the IP ranges of EC2 instances. I am aware of Elastic IP and what you propose. I upvoted your answer. I also noticed I was making an error in extracting data from JSON File, there are values for all regions. Thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Comment: Ah in that case yes all regions do exist in the JSON file :) that was next stop

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and needed to share it with a customer so built this online tool. I couldn't find anything online to do this easily, everything seemed to be search by IP address, not region/service. If anyone needs this in the future: https://shotstack.io/tools/aws-ip-search-tool/